# adding a button in an UIView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'm trying to add a button to a UIview, to cover the whole area of the view.. like this:

```
-(MBNHomeScreenButton*) initWithImage:(UIImage*)image 
              andHighlightedImage:(UIImage*)highlightedImage 
                         andTitle:(NSString*)aTitle 
                     withSelector:(SEL)actionButton
                      forDelegate:(UIViewController*)viewController{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 120);

    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image highlightedImage:highlightedImage];
    self.imageView.center = self.center;
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, HS_BUTTON_IMAGE_WIDTH, HS_BUTTON_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    self.imageView.highlighted = NO;
    [self addSubview:self.imageView];

    self.title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, HS_BUTTON_IMAGE_HEIGHT, HS_BUTTON_IMAGE_WIDTH + 20, 30)];
    self.title.text = aTitle;
    self.title.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    self.title.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [self addSubview:self.title];

    // This creates a transparent button over the view
    UIButton *button  = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    //button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [button setFrame:self.frame];
    [button addTarget:viewController action:actionButton forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview: button];
}
return self;}
```

In the ViewController I create the View like this:

```
m_newsHSButton = [[MBNHomeScreenButton alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:NEWS_SHADED_IMAGE]
                                        andHighlightedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:NEWS_HIGHLIGHTED_IMAGE]
                                                   andTitle:@"News" 
                                               withSelector:@selector(newsButtonPressed)
                                                forDelegate:self];

m_newsHSButton.center = CGPointMake(m_backgroundView.frame.size.width / 4, m_backgroundView.frame.size.height / 4);
[backgroundImgView addSubview:m_newsHSButton];
```

Still... the newsButtonPressed doesn't get called.

Can you help?
Thanks!

====================
[edit]
Ok... figured it out.. Thanks guys.
It was the fact that I was trying to add the view as a subview to a UIImageView with the last line:

```
[backgroundImgView addSubview:m_newsHSButton];
```

Apparently, it won't get touches anymore.

Thanks for the effort guys!

Comment: Can you show your method newsButtonPressed? I just tried your code with simple ViewController project and it is working fine. Can you confirm that it has the correct signature: - (void) newsButtonPressed.

Comment: There are lots of possibilities, check out [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1731377/154803).  Also I seem to recall that anything transparent (<0.1 alpha) does not get touches passed to it, so instead of clear try `[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:0.11]`

Comment: What's the value of `viewController` when you do `addTarget`? Could it be you need to use `self.viewController`?

Comment: Ok... so yes... the selector is good:  -(void) newsButtonPressed
{
 NSLog(@"newsButtonPressed");
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making the button a @property or instance variable in your custom view. Then call `[m_newsHSButton.button addTarget:self action:actionButton forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` from the viewController.